# How to Push Dynamic Object into an Array from a Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array with sub-array. I want to push the value of the sum of the sub-array into the main object array.

The sum of sub-array is determined by search array.

Here is the main array with sub-array:

```
const objectArray = [
  { 'name': 'Alpha', 'data': [{ 'subData': 'a', 'value': 1 }, { 'subData': 'a', 'value': 2 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 3 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 4 }, { 'subData': 'c', 'value': 5 }] },
  { 'name': 'Beta', 'data': [{ 'subData': 'a', 'value': 8 }, { 'subData': 'a', 'value': 9 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 10 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 11 }] }
]
```

Here is the search array:

```
   const searchArray = [ { 'search': 'a' }, { 'search': 'b' },{ 'search': 'c' }]
```

Here is what I have started:

```
for (let i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {

   for (let j = 0; j < searchArray.length; j++) {
     const filterObject = objectArray[i].data.filter(a => a.subData == searchArray[j].search);
     const sumValue = filterObject && filterObject.length > 0 ? filterObject.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + +b.value; }, 0) : 0;

     const keyName = searchArray[j].search;

     var objPush = {};
     objPush[keyName] = sumValue;
  
   //  console.log(' obj:', obj );
  
    }
}
```

Here, the object "objPush" is to be appended to objectArray so that the desired array is this:

```
const desiredArray = [
  { 'name': 'Alpha', 'a': 3, 'b': 7, 'c':5, 'data': [{ 'subData': 'a', 'value': 1 }, { 'subData': 'a', 'value': 2 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 3 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 4 }, { 'subData': 'c', 'value': 5 }] },
  { 'name': 'Beta', 'a': 17, 'b': 21, 'c':0, 'data': [{ 'subData': 'a', 'value': 8 }, { 'subData': 'a', 'value': 9 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 10 }, { 'subData': 'b', 'value': 11 }] }
]
```

How do I achieve my desired Array?

Comment: search Array is: a, b, and c. I am grouping the subData: a, b, c, and getting the sum of its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const objectArray = [
  {
    name: "Alpha",
    data: [
      { subData: "a", value: 1 },
      { subData: "a", value: 2 },
      { subData: "b", value: 3 },
      { subData: "b", value: 4 },
      { subData: "c", value: 5 },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Beta",
    data: [
      { subData: "a", value: 8 },
      { subData: "a", value: 9 },
      { subData: "b", value: 10 },
      { subData: "b", value: 11 },
    ],
  },
];
const searchArray = [{ search: "a" }, { search: "b" }, { search: "c" }];

const result = objectArray.map((obj) => {
  const temp = { ...obj };
  searchArray.forEach(({ search }) => {
    temp[search] = obj.data.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.subData === search ? acc + curr.value : acc),0);
  });
  return temp;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objectArray = [
  {
    name: 'Alpha',
    data: [
      { subData: 'a', value: 1 },
      { subData: 'a', value: 2 },
      { subData: 'b', value: 3 },
      { subData: 'b', value: 4 },
      { subData: 'c', value: 5 },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Beta',
    data: [
      { subData: 'a', value: 8 },
      { subData: 'a', value: 9 },
      { subData: 'b', value: 10 },
      { subData: 'b', value: 11 },
    ],
  },
];

function reduceData(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (acc[el.subData]) {
      acc[el.subData] += el.value;
    } else {
      acc[el.subData] = el.value || 0;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function handleArray(array) {
  return array.map((el) => ({ ...el, ...reduceData(el.data) }))
}

console.log(handleArray(objectArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you expect to use your `searchArray` in a more general sense since you're giving them all the same `search` key and not using it to specifify properties more specifically.

If you just want to aggregate all `subData` across all objects you can first extract all the unique `subData` values.

```
const sub_datum = [...new Set(objectArray.flatMap((o) => o.data.map((d) => d.subData)))];
```

And then `map()` over the array and aggregate each object's `data` array.

```js
const objectArray = [ { name: 'Alpha', data: [ { subData: 'a', value: 1 }, { subData: 'a', value: 2 }, { subData: 'b', value: 3 }, { subData: 'b', value: 4 }, { subData: 'c', value: 5 }, ], }, { name: 'Beta', data: [ { subData: 'a', value: 8 }, { subData: 'a', value: 9 }, { subData: 'b', value: 10 }, { subData: 'b', value: 11 }, ], }, ];

const aggregate_subdata = (arr, data_points) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (a, o) => ((a[o.subData] = a[o.subData] + o.value), a),
    Object.fromEntries(data_points.map((k) => [k, 0]))
  );

const sub_datum = [...new Set(objectArray.flatMap((o) => o.data.map((d) => d.subData)))];

const result = objectArray.map((o) => ({ ...o, ...aggregate_subdata(o.data, sub_datum) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```